# Azure Dev Ops: Can't Move Product Backlog Item to another Project

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ado

I have a two projects. One is freshly setup project on Azure DevOps using the SCRUM methodology while the other is Legacy conversion to SCRUM. I'm trying to move a singe Product Backlog from one project to the other to no avail, though ironically I can move tasks with no issues.

I've set up the Product Backlogs identically on both projects, from layouts and States all the way down to the same image and same color.

Is this a design feature, or am I missing something?

[Product Backlog Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3bW9.png)

Comment: Hi @Mac, How are things going? Is the suggestion in my answer helpful to you? If you have any questions about this ticket, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you get any note, warning or error message when you try to move the **`Product Backlog Item`**? What is the details of the message?

There is an important thing you need to know:

> You can't change type or move work items whose work item types support **test management** or that belong to the **Hidden Types Category**. This includes all work items that track tests—such as test cases, shared steps, and shared parameters—code review requests and responses, and feedback requests and responses.

So, please check whether the **`Product Backlog Item`** in your projects is associated with test management.

To view more details, you can reference to:

- [**Move work items, change work item type**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/move-change-type?view=azure-devops)
- [**Hidden types categories**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/agile-glossary?view=azure-devops#hidden-types-categories)